# Numbering with arraylists and lists

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

So I have the following code all in the same class

```
List<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();

private void viewPersons() {
    if (peopleList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No persons to display");
    }
    if (peopleList.isEmpty()!= true) {
        //for(int i = 0; i <= peopleList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(peopleList);
        //}
    }
}
```

There is another class called Person which the array holds reference to.

I get values from user input, which isn't important or the problem, but when this method runs (say I have Jon, 4110987654 and jjon@gmail.com as the user input for the three strings) I get

> "[Person@55f96302 Jon, 4110987654, jjon@gmail.com] as output from it."

If I entered another person's info, I would get it all on one line. It would look like

> "[Person@55f96302 Jon, 4110987654, jjon@gmail.com, Person@3d4eac69,
>   name, phone, email]"

But what I want is

> "Person@55f96302 Jon, 4110987654, jjon@gmail.com
>
> Person@3d4eac69, name, phone, email"

How do I seperate them so that each person's info is on separate lines and `"Person@55f96302"` is just a number, such as 1 or 2?

I'm just not sure what syntax should be added or what should change.

Here is the toString() in Person class

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(super.toString()).append(" ");
    builder.append(fullName).append(", ");
    builder.append(phoneNumber).append(", ");
    builder.append(email).append(" ");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: override the `toString()`  method of `Person` appropriately

Comment: and instead of `if (peopleList.isEmpty()!= true)` you can simply say as `else`

Comment: Can you show the Person class? Your output doesn't seem possible. If you didn't override toString() in the  Person class, it should only show `[Person@55f96302, Person@3d4eac69]`

Comment: We can't give you an exact solution without seeing the getters for the `Person` class.

Answer (score 3):

You were getting the output you mentioned above because you were trying to print an `ArrayList` directly, which contained `Person` objects for which `toString()` had no functionality.  Try this code:

```
List<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();

private void viewPersons() {
    if (peopleList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No persons to display");

    } else {
        for (Person p : peopleList) {
            // you can override Person.toString() however you want
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override java.lang.Objects class toString() method to format your list output.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options to print in your expected way.

1. You can iterate as Tim Biegeleisen mentioned in his answer. Which is simple enough for this one. If you're going to print like this only in this place not anywhere else in your code.
2. If you're going to need this similar kind of print need in multiple places, then you have to override ArrayList's toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

peopleList is arraylist. 
To print contents of arraylist in format mentioned by you 
You have to use for each loop and toString() method .
toString() method is from object class which you need to override.
You can use modified code below

```
List<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();

private void viewPersons() {
   if (peopleList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No persons to display");
   }
   else{
       //use of for each loop
       for(Person per : peopleList){ 
        //override toString() method
        System.out.println(per.toString());
       }
   }
}
```